# I can´t show service response in angular component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, metronic

I try to show a data in an angular component from a service, all the process from service to component is ok, but when i use the variable in html it not show the result.

I used this Metronic Template: https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic/angular/demo1/
Metronic Version:

```
"name": "metronic-angular-demo1",
"version": "7.1.0",
```

Angular version:

```
"@angular/cli": "~10.0.4",
```

I have the following angular component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GeneralResult } from 'src/app/models/general/general.model';
import { PointsService } from 'src/app/services/points/points.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private service: PointsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.service.getPointConfig().subscribe((result: GeneralResult) => {
      this.data = result.data;
    });
  }

}
```

This is the service

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { GeneralResult, ResultModel } from 'src/app/models/general/general.model';
import * as env from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PointsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPointConfig(): Observable<GeneralResult> {
    return this.http.post<GeneralResult>(env.serviceRoute.GET_POINTS_CONFIG, null);
  }
}
```

This is the HTML component

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of data; let i of index" class="row row-container-item-list">
                <div class="col-3">
                    {{ item.codePoint }}
                </div>
      
                <div class="col-3">
                    {{ item.namePoint }}
                </div>
               
                <div class="col-3">
                    {{ item.quantityPoint }}
                </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: I did add a button with a empty function in component.ts, when i click on the button, data works `<button (click)="go();">
    button
</button>  go() {
    
  }
`

Comment: can you share your resposne here or your GeneralResult modal and then only able to answer your question clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `*ngIf="data"` in parent tag.
try like this.

```
<div *ngIf="data">
  <div *ngFor="let item of data; let i of index" class="row row-container-item-list">
    <div class="col-3">
        {{ item.codePoint }}
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-3">
        {{ item.namePoint }}
    </div>
   
    <div class="col-3">
        {{ item.quantityPoint }}
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="data">
  <div *ngFor="let item of data; let i of index" class="row row-container-item-list">
    <div class="col-3">
        {{ item.codePoint }}
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-3">
        {{ item.namePoint }}
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-3">
        {{ item.quantityPoint }}
    </div>
    
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Let me know if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Trying a different variable to store the subscription. It might be conflicting with that.

```
data = [];
sub : any;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub= this.service.getPointConfig().subscribe((result: GeneralResult) => {
      this.data = [...result.data];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only responding because someone else might come across this question like I did. I am guessing OP did fix their error.

I have used the exact same metronic services as OP. The data is not initialized which means angular will throw an error while rendering the template. 2 simple fixes, one given by Piyush in their answer.

1. Use NgIf which will observe data till it's received and then render the component. Adding this tag will fix the error

> <div *ngIf="data">

2. Initialize the data before assigning the values. Has to be done either in the constructor or ngOnInit

> this.data = { codePoint : "", namePoint : "", quantityPoint :"" }

Also, you assigned subscription to this.data, don't do that. You want to dispose of your subscriptions when done, otherwise you can have memory leaks over time.

Since I mentioned memoryleaks, initializing the data is preferable to using NgIf on a strictly performance based metric.